# ConTeXt: String substitution to include macro

Tags: context, strings, substitution

## Background

A Markdown document uses certain strings that are to be typeset in a special way. In this case, we'd like to typeset `a.m.` and `p.m.` as  small caps wherever that text appears in the source document. That is:

```
11 a.m. → 11 AM
11 p.m. → 11 PM
```

ConTeXt LMTX, latest version.

## Problem

Hooking into ConTeXt's text processing algorithm.

## Code

The following snippet shows two parts. The first part represents the input source document. The second part shows how the text is meant to be replaced.

```tex
\starttext
  {\bf Markdown Input}

  Our grandmother clock rang 11 p.m. and we fled.

  Our grandmother clock rang 11 p.m., so we fled.

  Our grandmother clock rang 11 p.m. We fled.

  \blank[big]

  {\bf \ConTeXt{} Output}

  Our grandmother clock rang 11 \cap{pm} and we fled.

  Our grandmother clock rang 11 \cap{pm}, so we fled.

  Our grandmother clock rang 11 \cap{pm}. We fled.
\stoptext
```

English makes this a little bit more challenging than a straight substitution. For example:

> At 11 p.m. Captain Cook cooked a crooked cook's cuke.

Let's not worry about that case.

## Question

How do you perform a string replacement in ConTeXt without modifying the source document? Is there something like:

```
\definereplacement[SubstPostmeridian][
  match={[Pp].[Mm].]}
  replace={\cap{pm}}
]

\definereplacement[SubstMac][
  match={Mc(\W)}
  replace={M\sup{c}\1}
]
```

The second example would change "McGenius" into "MᶜGenius".

Comment: How are you inputting the markdown? Are you using an external converter like Pandoc, or are you using something from within ConTeXt like the `markdown` module?

Comment: I'm using my editor, [KeenWrite](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite), which integrates and tweaks [flexmark-java](https://github.com/vsch/flexmark-java). The Markdown is converted to XML prior to typesetting. I seem to recall that ConTeXt has the ability to perform text substitution, but I've completely forgotten how to set it up.

Comment: You're probably thinking of [`\replaceword`](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Ligatures#Replacements), which unfortunately doesn't seem to work with the periods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `translate` module:

```
\startbuffer
  Our grandmother clock rang 11 p.m. and we fled.

  Our grandmother clock rang 11 p.m., so we fled.

  Our grandmother clock rang 11 p.m. We fled.
\stopbuffer

\usemodule[translate]

\translateinput[ a.m.][ \cap{AM}]
\translateinput[ p.m.][ \cap{PM}]

\starttext
\getbuffer

\enableinputtranslation

\getbuffer

\disableinputtranslation

\getbuffer
\stoptext
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this produces the grammatically incorrect phrase of: "Our grandmother clock rang 11 PM We fled." The period after PM is missing. I think regexes and backreferences are needed.

Comment: Your regrex will produce the same output, right?

Comment: That particular example, yes. With regex, we could apply two different match conditions `match={[Pp].[Mm]. ([^:upper:])},` and `match={[Pp].[Mm]. ([:upper:])},` along with slightly different replacement patterns to solve the problem.

Comment: You can look into the code of `m-translate.mkiv`. It hooks into `textlineactions` to do the replacement one by one. It should be possible to write a standalone lpeg based expression to do the translation that you want.